# Why is my Python customtkinter Frame's width not working?

Tags: python, width, sidebar, customtkinter

I'm trying to make a Sidebar in customtkinter, but the width is not being set and the Frame is taking up the full speed.

My code looks like this:

```
class Sidebar(customtkinter.CTkFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent, fg_color="gray", width=20)
        self.controller = controller
        
        heading = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Sidebar")
        heading.pack(side=customtkinter.TOP)
```

Yet the frame still takes up the full screen. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the frame will take up the size it needs to, width is what the maximum size of the frame is.

If youre looking for the frame to take up 1/2 the screen something like

```
app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

[link to documentation if i dont make sense or got something wrong :D](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/tutorial/grid-system)